# Add input with add button in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, addition

When I click on the add button, it should add an input and I have to save it.

Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/432yz8qg/285/) but with Input. But the problem is the input are all different so that's why I don't know how to do

My code :

```
class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChangeCategorie = this.handleChangeCategorie.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      // I think it should be an array but I don't know
      valueCategorie: ""
    };
  }
  addCategorie(){
    //Something to add input 
  }
  handleSubmit() {
    //Make something with the categorie
  }

  handleChangeCategorie(e) {
    // I don't know if I can use this function for all Input
    this.setState({ valueCategorie: e.target.value });
  }
  render() {
    return <div className="container">              
        <input type="text" value={this.state.valueCategorie} onChange={this.handleChangeCategorie} />
        <Button onClick={this.addCategorie}>Add Input</Button>
        <Button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Send</Button>
      </div>;
  }
}
```

I don't think it's the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45543419/add-inputs-in-react-with-add-button) because he uses something to count. Maybe there is an other way to it ? Or is it the only way ?

Comment: How is this different from the linked question?

Comment: Just take the example you provided and change with inputs. You can keep an array of JSX elements and render it to the page. When a user clicks add, just push new input to that array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Inputs in React with add button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45543419/add-inputs-in-react-with-add-button)

Answer (score 1):

Say you have an array of your different inputs,

```
let inputArray = [<input id="1"/>,<input id="2"/>,<input id="3"/>]
```

Declare state,
    state={
       inputsRenderingArray:[]
    }

Functions to add the input dynamically,

```
AddFirst=()=>this.setState({inputsRenderingArray:[...this.state.inputsRenderingArray, inputArray[0]]})

AddSecond=()=>this.setState({inputsRenderingArray:[...this.state.inputsRenderingArray, inputArray[1]]})

AddThird=()=>this.setState({inputsRenderingArray:[...this.state.inputsRenderingArray, inputArray[2]]})
```

in the render, onclick of add button push these items into the renderable array,
    render(){

```
return(
   <Button onClick={AddFirst}>Add First</Button>
   <Button onClick={AddSecond}>Add Second</Button>
   <Button onClick={AddSecond}>Add Second</Button>

   {this.state.inputsRenderingArray}
)

}
```